# Rerequest redirect but does not ask for declined permission

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need user's email for my facebook app and I want to reask it to the user if he unchecked the permission so I used auth_type : rerequest. The redirection works but there is no way for the user to accept the permissions he has declined.

SDK JS v 2.2

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                handleUrlStuff();
            } else {
                whenLoginFailed();
            }
        },
        {
            'scope' : 'email',
            'auth_type' : 'rerequest'
        });
```

[image]

[image]

On this screen email doesn't appear and i can't check/uncheck date of birth. Is someone know why this happens ?

Comment: Re-asking directly if the user choose not to give it to you is not allowed. You need to explain why you need it and have a button the user can click if they change their mind and what to give it to you.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input. Can you redirect me on a place where I can find some example ?